# Where is the entry to the underground place of power in Velen?

Tags: the-witcher-3

South of Midcopse and north of Byways there is a place of power. It's near an crumbled tower on which a Noonwraith roams. It seems to be underground yet I cannot find its entrance anywhere around.

[image: standing ontop the place of power]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go east to the sea and follow the shore to the south:

[image: path to entry marked on map]
[image: entrance of the cave leading to the underground place of power]

You will then come across a cave entry. It's the same cave that is part of a sidequest with Keira Metz.

Inside you find the Place of Power and also a hidden treasure after a bit of climbing.

---

There's also a video guide on YouTube: