# Can the Velen "Place of Power" be accessed from the expansion DLC in Witcher 3?

Tags: the-witcher-3, the-witcher-3-blood-and-wine, the-witcher-3-hearts-of-stone

I've been trying to access the underground Place of Power shown in this question:

[Where is the entry to the underground place of power in Velen?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/297971/where-is-the-entry-to-the-underground-place-of-power-in-velen)

But there is a large door blocking my access to the room I need to get to.

[image: Velen elven ruins]

Is this because I'm playing through the expansion packs, instead of going back and doing this quest from the main storyline?   Or is there some way to open this door and I'm just not "getting it" somehow?

Does anyone know if this is a "bug" or a "feature?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That door is a puzzle normally done with Keira Metz in the "Magic Lamp" side quest at the end of the main "Wandering in the Dark" quest.

I'm not sure if you can do it without Keira to read the runes. See if you can light the torches of the four statues - you have to get the order right. This will be more difficult without Keira as the runes she reads contain a riddle giving the correct order.

Comment: Ugh, that's what I was afraid of.   It looks impossible to light the torches at this point, also.   Igni doesn't work and there are no prompts to light them using "[E] Interact" either.   Sigh...  Guess I'll cross this Place of Power off my list and go on!   Thanks.